# How can i create a loopback remote method for search

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, loopbackjs, loopback

In my loopback application i have a model named test. I need to search details and display the details based on multiple criteria. that is the search fields are status, priority, message and id. i want to dispalt the details based on these search fields. suppose i give status is open and priority is low the details should be satisfied with both these condition(that is "AND" operator).How should i implement this? My db is Arango Db. what i have is common/models/test.js

test.js

```
 module.exports = function (Test) {
 Test.search = function(callback){

 }
 };
```

How should i implement this? I am new to loopback and angular. Any help will really helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a remote method is documented [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html).

It requires two things. First, create the function that will be called remotely. Here, you've called it `search`.
Function parameters should include all request arguments (`status` `priority` `message` `id`) and a callback as last argument.

Then, register this function as a remote method.

In your case, it should give the following code

```
module.exports = function(Test){

    Test.search = function(status, priority, message, id, cb) {
      var results = ...// Your custom logic to find the results

      if (err) return cb(err); // if something went wrong. err is returned by your custom logic
      cb(null, results); // if results were found
    }

    Test.remoteMethod('search', {
          http: {
            verb: 'get'
          },
          accepts: [
            {arg: 'status', type: 'string', http: { source: 'query' } },
            {arg: 'priority', type: 'string', http: { source: 'query' } },
            {arg: 'message', type: 'string', http: { source: 'query' } },
            {arg: 'id', type: 'number'},
          ],
          returns: {arg: 'results', type: 'Object'} // To return a JSON object for instance
    });
};
```

Then, call your method with `GET api/Tests/search?status=open&priority=high&...`

For searching entries, you might also use the [querying approach](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html)

Comment: By default loopback remote methods are POST requests.